# Token-based Auth for an Android/Rest (Java) application

Tags: java, android, rest, oauth, restful-authentication

I'm developping a backend REST API for a mobile app and I am now looking to implement token-based authentication for it to avoid having to prompt the user to login on every run of the app ..

the user will have a token for a certain time before being obligated to give the username and password again, it's like managing sessions that have limited among of time, anyway I've gone through the APIs that provides this kind of Authentication mechanism and notice that OAuth is highly rated but haven't found any exemple that suits my cas ..

I do't know if this is the good way to ensure authentication for app or there's other mechanisms ..

if you have any suggestions, ideas or any sort of help, feel free to comment ..

Comment: take a look at this question and the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368548/is-oauth-good-choice-for-restful-api-in-this-saas-scenario?rq=1